# Combine column from multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to create a query that returns a list of campaign usage history. An order can be applied multiple campaigns.

`orderId   CampaignName DiscountAmount
-----------------------------------
1           50% Off        $5.20
1           10% Off        $1.30
1           5%  Off        $0.57`

How can I create a query that returns a single row with multiple columns?

`orderId  Campaign1 Campaign2 Campaign3 Discount1 Discount2 Discount3 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1          50% Off  10% Off   5% Off    $5.20      $1.30    $0.57`

Comment: How many campaigns can be on an order?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An order can have maximum 3 campaigns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of campaigns per orderId, consider a simple conditional aggregation in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([orderId] int,[CampaignName] varchar(50),[DiscountAmount] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'50% Off','$5.20')
,(1,'10% Off','$1.30')
,(1,'5% Off','$0.57')

Select orderId
      ,Campaign1 = max(case when RN=1 then CampaignName end)
      ,Campaign2 = max(case when RN=2 then CampaignName end)
      ,Campaign3 = max(case when RN=3 then CampaignName end)
      ,Discount1 = max(case when RN=1 then DiscountAmount end)
      ,Discount2 = max(case when RN=2 then DiscountAmount end)
      ,Discount3 = max(case when RN=3 then DiscountAmount end)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = row_number() over(partition by orderId order by (select null))
         From @YourTable
       ) A
 Group By OrderID
```

**Returns**

```
orderId Campaign1   Campaign2   Campaign3   Discount1   Discount2   Discount3
1       50% Off     10% Off     5% Off      $5.20       $1.30       $0.57
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John. My problem has been solved thanks to you.

Comment: @İsmailDoğan Always happy to help